# What is the shopify workflow process for a site already in production that requires a completely new design for specific pages

Tags: shopify

I have never worked with shopify before but I have experience with other CMS's.

I recently got a client with a website already live and with some quick research, I see that I need to create a private app and manage the site with themekit.

What I need help with is how to properly set up a staging/dev environment to view the changes I make before pushing the changes into production.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a theme backup by duplicating your current theme. and make code changes in to this theme ( you can preview your changes without affecting live theme/store) when you and your client happy with the changes you can publish this theme to live.

Have a look how to backup / duplicate theme.

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/using-themes/managing-themes/duplicating-themes

Hope this will help

Comment: Hey Bhargav, this makes sense. Thanks!